# MySql dead lock root cause - Hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

I have a code snippet in hibernate, structured like below.

This method is a common method and when I use two different locks (In parallel stream) I end up having dead lock scenario. I am trying to understand the root cause of the dead lock.

[Spring/JPA/Hibernate/MySql]

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void someMethod(String lockName) { // Lock name can be of two types

     jpaRepository.lock(lockName, TIMEOUT_10_SECONDS);

     List<Object> values = jpaRepository.findByDate();

     Integer sequence = jpaRepository.getNextSequenceValue(); // Fetches next value from sequence generator

     //...... set sequence numbers to object

     jpaRepository.updateSequence(); // A named query here to update sequence with latest value

     jpaRepository.saveAll(); // JPA's persist call
}
```

Innodb status

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2022-03-24 00:05:03 0x16c113000
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2000, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 6 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 54, OS thread handle 6131019776, query id 976 localhost 127.0.0.1 root update
/* mysql-connector-java-8.0.27 (Revision: e920b979015ae7117d60d72bcc8f077a839cd791 */ insert into SequenceId (invoice_id, post_processed_sequence_value, sequence_id, sequence_value) values (1648076703544, '79', '2000', 79)

*** (1) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 3 page no 6 n bits 192 index invoice_id of table `sequenceid` trx id 2000 lock mode S
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;


*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 3 page no 6 n bits 192 index invoice_id of table `sequenceid` trx id 2000 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;


*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1999, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 6 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 53, OS thread handle 6132133888, query id 977 localhost 127.0.0.1 root update
/* mysql-connector-java-8.0.27 (Revision: e920b979015ae7117d60d72bcc8f077a839cd791) */ insert into SequenceId (ref_id, post_processed_sequence_value, sequence_id, sequence_value) values (1648076703512, '50046', '1000', 50046)

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 3 page no 6 n bits 192 index invoice_id of table `sequenceid` trx id 1999 lock mode S
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;


*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 3 page no 6 n bits 192 index invoice_id of table `sequenceid` trx id 1999 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

Comment: You must have two transactions each holding a lock the other needs to complete. How they get in that state would certainly depend on what you are saving, the ordering of the statements, what is being locked, statement timing etc. You need to debug and give information if you need help, as what you have posted is too generic - at the very least, log the SQL involved.

Comment: And use innodb status monitor to get the details on what's causing the deadlock. I agree with @Chris, your code is too general and far removed from mysql to comment on the cause of the deadlock!

Comment: I thought there is something obvious I am missing so added a generic question. I have now added more details.

Comment: The type of lock is important. Looks like they both get a "lock mode S" lock, which prevents any other thread from obtaining the "lock_mode X" they need for an insert. II don't know mysql, but assume since both transactions seem to hold the same lock s, that it is a read lock preventing others from getting an exclusive write lock on the data. Don't use a shared read lock and your transactions shouldn't deadlock (or have a much smaller chance of hitting this issue). see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a transaction is executed in serializable isolation read statements acquire shared lock.
Please find the details below

1. Thread 1 tries to insert record by acquiring key. For insert there is no way we can hold a key. So mysql acquires a shared lock on the latest record before inserting.
2. Thread 2 tries to update the latest record and acquires the shared lock before inserting.

Now Thread 1 and Thread 2 are competing for the same lock and it causes deadlock.